# hide remove button <span> and remove <li> on click JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

1. I would like to display the title of a task when `onclick`, it gives me "remove" `text(span)` as well. I tried to display my task without remove when a user clicks on each list... but it wont work..
2. I also want to remove each list when a user clicks on the `remove button`.. Can you give me some tips? I have tried multiple ways.. but it wont work :(

I have attached the image of my to do list app.

I appreciate it in advance!

```js
var title = document.getElementById('title');
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var li = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

var addBtn = document.getElementById('add-btn');
var i;

var span = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

var listspan = document.getElementById('list-span');
list.addEventListener('click', activeItem);

function activeItem(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName == 'LI') {
    document.getElementById("list-span").style.visibility = "";
    title.innerHTML = event.target.innerText;
    for (var i = 0; i < event.target.parentNode.children.length; i++) {
      event.target.parentNode.children[i].removeAttribute('class');
    }
    event.target.setAttribute('class', 'active');
  }
}


addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var txt = prompt('add task');
  list.innerHTML += '<li>' + txt + '<span>' + "REMOVE" + '</span>' + '</li>';
  list.addEventListener('click', activeItem);
});
```

```html
<section class="container">


  <div class="header-div">
    <h1 id='title'>ADD A TASK</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="button-div">
    <button id="add-btn">ADD A TASK</button>
  </div>

  <div class="list-div">
    <ul id='list'>
      <li>Walk my dog<span id="list-span">remove</span></li>
      <li>Go grocery shopping<span id="list-span">remove</span></li>
      <li>Call mom<span id="list-span">remove</span></li>
      <li>Do laundry<span id="list-span">remove</span></li>
      <li>Call Jane<span id="list-span">remove</span></li>
      <li>Eat lunch<span id="list-span">remove</span></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: can you please add your HTML

Comment: I just did! Please take a look

Comment: `#title span { display: none }`

Comment: you could put text and remove in separate tags like so <li><span data-action='active'>Walk my dog</span><span data-action='remove'>remove</span></li>, then check which one is clicked by checking data attribute